# android dialog can not fund function for setPositiveButton()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter

I have a listener for a specific item in my adapter. When I click it I want to show a dialog. My problem is that I can not get my dialog "builder.setPositiveButton("Cancel", new deleteRow());" to work. I can never get it to find any of my functions. How can I have my dialog run a function?

In my fragment

```
public void getSavedVideos() {
        mydb = new MySQLiteHelper(getActivity());
        listView.setEmptyView(rootview.findViewById(R.id.noSavedVideosTextView));

        //Get IDs of all rows in the db
        ArrayList savedVideoIDs = mydb.getAllSavedVideo();

        mSavedVideoAdapter = new SavedVideoAdapter(getActivity(), savedVideoIDs, mydb);
        listView.setAdapter(mSavedVideoAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                View cancel = view.findViewById(R.id.x);
                cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        getActivity().showDialog(DIALOG_ALERT);
                    }
                });

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), UploadVideoActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
            @Override
            protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
                switch (id) {
                    case DIALOG_ALERT:
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                        builder.setTitle("Remove Video");
                        builder.setMessage("hkjh.");
                        builder.setCancelable(true);
                        builder.setPositiveButton("Cancel", new CancelOnClickListener());
                        builder.setNegativeButton("Remove", new deleteRow());
                        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                        dialog.show();
                }
                return onCreateDialog(id);
            }

        });


    }
    public void deleteRow() {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

change this :

```
builder.setNegativeButton("Remove", new deleteRow());
```

to this :

```
 ad.setPositiveButton("Buy",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    //do everi ting you want
                }
            });
```

it work

here sample dialog with action :

```
AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            ad.setTitle("PRO_VISION");
            ad.setMessage("for use Settings you must buy pro_vision only pro user can use this");
            ad.setPositiveButton("Buy",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    Intent is = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity4.class);
                    startActivityForResult(is,12);
                }
            });
            ad.setNegativeButton("cancel",null);
            ad.show();
```

use this on onCreate in the some view setOnClickListener
it must be work

Comment: That appears to work. Now I am seeing that onCreateDialog() never gets called. Any ideas?

Comment: dont build dialog in oncreatedialog use your code in oncreate and use clickListener to build dialog if you want build a dialog in onCreatedialog you must use FragmentActivity